# Select all surfaces in a part instance in Abaqus

Tags: python, interaction, surface, abaqus

I'm currently stuck on selecting all the surfaces in a part instance, so that I can use it to create a surface to surface explicit contact.

The surfaces in this part instance are all pre-created and then imported into abaqus, and they are nameed as 'Surf-1', 'Surf-2'....

In order to create a surface to surface contact explicit object, I have to select two "surfaces", a master and a slave. I need to select all the surfaces of this part instance because It's dropped onto another part so any surface can be in contact with the model. I've done the procedure manually and it works perfectly . So right now I'm not sure how I can select all the surfaces at once via python script...

In the abaqus script reference manual, for creating the surface to surface contact exp object,

22.64.1 SurfaceToSurfaceContactExp(...)

This method creates a SurfaceToSurfaceContactExp object.

Path
     mdb.models[name].SurfaceToSurfaceContactExp

Required arguments

```
name
createStepName
master
        A Region object specifying the master surface.
slave
        A Region object specifying the slave surface.
```

Is there any way that I can use a command like selecting all the surfaces that are already created on a specific part instance and save that as a region object?? So that I can refer it later as a "master" while creating surface to surface contact exp?

Comment: If you managed to do this manually, did you try looking at abaqus.rpy to see which commands were issued when performing the task manually?

Comment: I think you need to call `SurfaceToSurface..` on each pair ( which you can readily do in a loop ).  Alternately you need to extract all the associated faces and define a new surface.  This gets tricky since you need to track which side of each face to assign to the surface (which is hard to script)